# Cellfun : How to sum each row in a cell array of matrices? Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, cells

Say I have 3x3 cells, each cell containing a matrix of 9x9, how would I go about using cellfun to sum each row of the entire cell array?

I keep obtaining the error ''bad cell reference'' when I try to use the : in the curly brackets.

I'd rather not convert it to a matrix then back to cells again.

Many thanks for your wisdom guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for summing row of each matrix with a cell , if you read the documentation of `cellfun` carefully, I think you should be able to get it.

```
clc;
clear all;
a=cell(3,3);
for i=1:3
    for j=1:3
        a{i,j}=randi(10,[9 9]);
    end
end

row_sum_cell=cellfun(@(a) sum(a,2),a,'UniformOutput',false);
```

The following solution sums the entire row across the cell array:

```
clc;
clear all;
a=cell(3,3);
for i=1:3
    for j=1:3
        a{i,j}=randi(10,[9 9]);   %generating the cell array
    end
end

[r,c]=size(a);          %getting the size of the array to concatenate it at runtime
horzCat_A=cell(r,1);

for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        horzCat_A{i,1}=[horzCat_A{i,1} a{i,j}];    %concatenating
    end
end

%after getting a concatenated matrix, apply a cellfun same as in previous example.
cell_row_sum=cellfun(@(horzCat_A) sum(horzCat_A,2),horzCat_A,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: Many thanks, I was able to sum each matrix within each cell in a number of ways but I was hoping to sum the entire row across the cell array.That I can't seem to figure out :)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. So you split the cell arrays up into rows, then performed the cellfun, learned a lot from this thank you!

Comment: Instead of saying "I split the arrays into rows", I would say I concatenate the matrices in each row of cell array column-wise

Answer (score 2):

If you mean sum each row in each cell entry maybe you can do something like this:

```
% random input
A = cell(3,3);
for i=1:9
    A{i} = randi(9,3,3);
end;

B = cellfun(@(x) sum(x, 2), A, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

**Update:** To sum all rows across the cell array, as if it was a matrix, without converting to a matrix modify the above as:

```
B = num2cell(zeros(3, 1)); % initialize
for i=1:3
    B = cellfun(@plus, B, A(:,i), 'UniformOutput', false); % add column-wise
end
B = cellfun(@(x) sum(x, 2), B, 'UniformOutput', false); % add within each remaning cell
```

This will give a `3x1` cell of `3x1` arrays with the sums across rows.

Comment: You can use `num2cell(rand(3))` for the random input generation

Comment: Ah thank you but I meant the sum of each row across the entire cell array!

Comment: @Tetra thanks! By _each row_ you mean to obtain a single 3x3 matrix of the element-wise sum for each of the 9 arrays, i.e. the `cellfun` equivalent version of `C=0; for i=1:9, C = C + (A{i}); end`?

Comment: @GuntherStruyf good point, with `mat2cell` though for matrix cell entries.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. I would like a vector at the end which is the sum of each row across the entire cell array, as if the cell array were a matrix. I'm trying to avoid converting cells to matrices because I have to convert it back to cells :)

Comment: See an extension/update above, based on the original suggestion. If you need a vector as an output though, i.e. `B = cell2mat(B),` @GuntherStruyf's solution is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [cell2mat](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/cell2mat.html) and [num2cell](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html):

```
a=num2cell(randi(10,3)); % random input generation

result = num2cell(sum(cell2mat(a),2));
```

Next question is then: Why are you working with a cell matrix of scalars? Can't you just work with an ordinary matrix (which you can obtain using `cell2mat`)?

Comment: Yes, I considered doing this and then reconverting it back into cells but the next part of my code is much better done in cell form. I thought it might be quicker to use cellfun instead of converting an array of cells to a matrix then back to an array of cells. Many thanks for your help.